# Could be solved a NP-complete problem in constant time?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, p-vs-np

Under the assumption that P would be equal to NP, it could exist a NP-complete problem that is solved in constant time?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write down the definition of NP-complete. Then take your assumption that P = NP, so in the definition of NP-completeness you can replace "NP" with "P". Figure out which functions exactly are NP-complete. (Hint: There is a simple and obvious solution that is almost but not *quite* correct. Read the definition carefully). Do these functions contain any constant time solvable problems?

Each step is actually quite simple, you just have to follow all the definitions very precisely.